# Copy and paste a new tab page into MSForms.Page

Tags: excel, vba, multipage

I have a UserForm in Excel with MultiPage object. I need to add more tab pages into the MultiPage object dynamically, by copying and pasting one of the existing tab pages. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using this piece of code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    '~~> Change 1 to the respective page index which you want to replicate
    MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls.Copy

    '~~> Add a New page
    MultiPage1.Pages.Add

    '~~> Paste the copied controls
    MultiPage1.Pages(MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1).Paste

End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddharth,Thank you for your response. I just did it and it worked fine in a sample code, but when I integrated it with my code, Excel restarts at the MultiPage1.Pages.Add line. I think it is because I have a lot of controls in each existing tab page. I'm trying to use TabStrip instead of MultiPage. This way I can use a single set of controls for all the tab pages.